# How to use a custom post type template for multiple custom post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am currently building an site for a client which is integrate in WordPress. The site is divided by two parts. One is the public area of the website and the other is the client area for members only. The last one I have realized with the plugin PA Login & Access from Codecanyon.

I was wondering if you can use one template for a range of custom post types, in my example `downloads, timesheets and events`. So these 3 custom post types uses the same template.

Thanks. Casper

Comment: Are you create a page for display private area??

Comment: If only authenticated users can access the custom post type, why not just create a custom post type page template?

Comment: @rnevius Yes, but if I have four custom post types like `downloads, thimesheets, events and dashboard` and all of these CPT should have the same template, how can I create a template that will use for these four CPT?

Comment: Like in `archive-all.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this to point to the file you want for the single template

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'change_template', 1, 5 );

public function change_template($template_path) {

    if( get_post_type() == 'myposttype' ||  get_post_type() == 'myanotherposttype' ):
        if( is_single() ):  
                $template_path = 'full path to your file.php';
        endif;      
    endif;
    return $template_path;

}
```